# Dart - Type Conflicts

Tags: dart, protocol-buffers

I'm currently working with a proto file which defines a number of types in use by a system.

Compiling this to dart with protoc works fine however trying to use it in a project is causing issue

One of the messages defined in the proto is `String` which has a `string` value, this seems to conflict with Darts core `String` type, I've put a snippet of the generated code below:

```
import 'dart:core' show int, bool, double, String, List, Map, override;
import 'package:fixnum/fixnum.dart';
import 'package:protobuf/protobuf.dart' as $pb;
import 'Framework.pbenum.dart';
export 'Framework.pbenum.dart';

class String extends $pb.GeneratedMessage {
  static final $pb.BuilderInfo _i = new $pb.BuilderInfo('String', package: const $pb.PackageName('sila2.org.silastandard'))
    ..aOS(1, 'value')
    ..hasRequiredFields = false
  ;

  String() : super();
  String.fromBuffer(List<int> i, [$pb.ExtensionRegistry r = $pb.ExtensionRegistry.EMPTY]) : super.fromBuffer(i, r);
  String.fromJson(String i, [$pb.ExtensionRegistry r = $pb.ExtensionRegistry.EMPTY]) : super.fromJson(i, r);
  String clone() => new String()..mergeFromMessage(this);
  String copyWith(void Function(String) updates) => super.copyWith((message) => updates(message as String));
  $pb.BuilderInfo get info_ => _i;
  static String create() => new String();
  String createEmptyInstance() => create();
  static $pb.PbList<String> createRepeated() => new $pb.PbList<String>();
  static String getDefault() => _defaultInstance ??= create()..freeze();
  static String _defaultInstance;
  static void $checkItem(String v) {
    if (v is! String) $pb.checkItemFailed(v, _i.qualifiedMessageName);
  }

  // Warning here
  String get value => $_getS(0, '');
  set value(String v) { $_setString(0, v); }
  bool hasValue() => $_has(0);
  void clearValue() => clearField(1);
}
```

I'm getting errors on the `value` property as it's unclear whether its to get/set a standard Dart String or the Proto Message String.

I can't change the proto so I've tried altering the import and prefixing a name where needed:

```
import 'dart:core' show int, bool, double, List, Map, override;
import 'dart:core' as core;

core.String get value => $_getS(0, '');
set value(core.String v) { $_setString(0, v);
```

But this isn't ideal as I don't want to be modifying generated code, is there a more correct way to do this?

Copy of the error below:

`Error: The argument type 'String (.../Framework.pb.dart)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String (C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\core\string.dart)'. (argument_type_not_assignable at (.../Framework.pb.dart:50)`

Proto Snippet:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message String {
    string value = 1;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the exact and full error message?

Comment: Can you please clarify what "One of the messages defined in the proto is String which has a string" means exactly?

Comment: Does the error go away if you change the name of the message from `String` to for example `StringX`?

Comment: Added snippets of the error and proto file, it defines a message called String which contains a string called value

Comment: I see. So it's about the generated getter missing the `core` prefix? I'd create a bug report for that.

Comment: Yes changing the proto works, but it's not something I'll have control over unfortunately

Comment: The core prefix is my own solution, I don't know if Dart offers anything more elegant

Comment: I don't think so, but if the generated code always uses prefixed imports for core identifiers, then such conflicts are prevented generally. Some other code generation packages do this by default AFAIK.

Comment: naming a protobuf type `String` has to be one of the stupidiest things the author of this scheme could do... I bet this would break in most Protobuf language's implementations.

Comment: You'll need to file an issue at https://github.com/dart-lang/protobuf or manually modify the code as you have. It's possible it won't be solved in the protobuf compiler since using a proto with the same name as a core type seems like a really bad idea.

Comment: I agree it's not a good idea, I'll post an issue to the repo and in the meantime I'll just have to apply my modification